# JavaScript function to create HTML select option elements

Tags: javascript, html5, form, dom

I made this function to get rid of writing numerical option values in a HTML-select manually.

From what I have seen so far it works as expected. But hints and suggestions are welcome anyway.

```js
// Trying it out.
var selects = document.querySelectorAll('.drop-down');
selects = Array.prototype.slice.call(selects);

createOptions(selects[0], -9, 9, 8);

for (var i = 1; i < selects.length; i++) {
  createOptions( selects[i], 
                 i * (-1 * Math.pow(10, i)),
                 i * Math.pow(10, i));
}

// The actual function ...

// The 1st Parameter is the HTML-element, the
// second is the bottom-limit, the third the
// upper limit. 
// The fourth, optional parameter allows to
// define the selected-option.

function createOptions( selectElement,
                        countOptionsStart,
                        countOptionsEnd,
                        preSelected ) {
    var bottom = countOptionsStart + '';
    var top = countOptionsEnd + '';
    var demand; // Count of needed chars.
  
    preSelected = preSelected || 0;
  
    var getLeadingZeros = function(demand, value) {
      var chars = value.toString() // Convert to string.
                       .split(''); // Make an array.
      // As long as the count of chars is less then
      // the demanded count iterate ...
      while (chars.length < demand) {
        // If the first element in the array contains
        // an minus ('-') then use splice() for to
        // add a zero at index 1.
        if (chars[0] === '-') {
          chars.splice(1, 0, '0');
        } else {
          // ... otherwise add the zero at the 
          // beginning.
          chars.unshift('0');
        }
      }
      // Concat the array-elements to a string and
      // return this string.
      return chars.join('');
    }
    
    // The longer string is taken.
    demand = bottom.length >= top.length ? bottom.length : top.length;
    
    // Constructing at adding the option-elements.
   for (var i = countOptionsStart; i <= countOptionsEnd; i++) {
     var option = document.createElement('option');
     var optionInner;
      var innerHTML = i + '';
      
      if (innerHTML.length < demand) 
        innerHTML = getLeadingZeros(demand, innerHTML);
      
      optionInner = document.createTextNode(innerHTML);
     option.setAttribute('value', i);
   
     if (i === preSelected) option.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
   
     option.appendChild(optionInner);
     selectElement.appendChild(option);   
   }
}
```

```html
<select class="drop-down"></select>
<select class="drop-down"></select>
<select class="drop-down"></select>
<select class="drop-down"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a warning: in its current implementation your code works *only if* `countOptionsStart` is less than or equal to `countOptionsEnd`!
So depending on your actual needs you should check this case to exit without generating options, or adapt code to work also in this case.

In the other hand, I suggest you some improvements about process of filling value with zeroes. It dramatically reduces code size, and probably works faster:

```js
// Trying it out.
var selects = document.querySelectorAll('.drop-down');
selects = Array.prototype.slice.call(selects);

createOptions(selects[0], -9, 9, 8);

for (var i = 1; i < selects.length; i++) {
  createOptions( selects[i], 
                 i * (-1 * Math.pow(10, i)),
                 i * Math.pow(10, i));
}

function createOptions( selectElement,
                        countOptionsStart,
                        countOptionsEnd,
                        preSelected ) {
  preSelected = preSelected || 0;
  demand = Math.max(
    countOptionsStart.toString().length,
    countOptionsEnd.toString().length);
  for (var i = countOptionsStart; i <= countOptionsEnd; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option'),
        strI = Math.abs(i) + '',
        sign = i < 0 ? '-' : '',
        fill = i < 0 ? demand -1 : demand;
    option.setAttribute('value', i);
    if (i === preSelected) option.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
    option.innerHTML = sign + '0'.repeat(fill - strI.length) + strI;
    selectElement.appendChild(option);   
  }
}
```

```html
<select class="drop-down"></select>
<select class="drop-down"></select>
<select class="drop-down"></select>
<select class="drop-down"></select>
```